# How can I find why my code is working on localhost but not working on Heroku PostgreSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, postgresql

> SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = character varying
> LINE 1: ...m "roles" inner join "admin_role" on "roles"."id" = "admin_r...
> ^
> HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types.
> You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select "roles".*, "admin_role"."admin_id" as "pivot_admin_id", "admin_role"."role_id" as "pivot_role_id" from "roles" inner join "admin_role" on "roles"."id" = "admin_role"."role_id" where "admin_role"."admin_id" = 1) (View: /app/resources/views/admin/partials/sidebar.blade.php) (View: /app/resources/views/admin/partials/sidebar.blade.php) (View: /app/resources/views/admin/partials/sidebar.blade.php)

Comment: You have a database error, `No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts`. I assume this is because your query is different between local and remote (or maybe even your table structure is different).

Comment: Could you add a table definition into your question?

Comment: Make sure your table definitions are precisely the same between two environments.

Comment: `"roles"."id" = "admin_role"."role_id"::INT`?

Answer (score 0):

`roles.id` and `admin_role.role_id` likely have different data types - one might be an integer, the other a string. You'll want to make sure both are integers.